# No puedo hacer referencia a objetos del DOM desde un Custom Control Cognos Analytics

Tags: javascript, dom, requirejs

He creado un Custom Control para Cognos Analytics que simula que el usuario hace click en el menú de ejecutar del informe y en la opción de ejecutar en PDF al hacer click en un icono con una imagen en PDF. El custom control se carga de forma automática mediante requirejs. El menú es este y de lo que se trata es de simular dos clicks.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
define( ['jquery'], function() {
"use strict";

var gImagen;
var gFormatoSalida;
/*
Posibles valores de gFormatoSalida
0 --> HTML
1 --> PDF
2 --> Excel 2017
3 --> Excel 2017 Data
4 --> CSV
*/

function Control(){
};

Control.prototype.initialize = function( oControlHost, fnDoneInitializing ){
    this.m_oControlHost = oControlHost;
    this.gImagen = this.getConfigurationValue( "urlImagen", '');
    this.gFormatoSalida = this.getConfigurationValue( "formatoSalida", '');
    fnDoneInitializing();

};

Control.prototype.destroy = function( oControlHost ){
    this.m_oControlHost = null;
};

Control.prototype.getConfigurationValue = function( sName, sDefaultValue ){
    var o = this.m_oControlHost.configuration;
    return ( o && ( o[sName] !== undefined ) ) ? o[sName] : sDefaultValue;
};


Control.prototype.draw = function( oControlHost ){
    var elContainer = oControlHost.container;
    elContainer.innerHTML ='<img class="imgExec" src="' + this.gImagen +'"></img>';
    $(".imgExec").on("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("com.ibm.bi.authoring.runBtn.menu").click();
        var botonPDF= $("li.commonMenuItem");
        botonPDF.get(this.gFormatoSalida).click(); //Ejecuta en PDF
    }); 
};

return Control;
});
```

El código falla porque el objeto "com.ibm.bi.authoring.runBtn.menu" no está definido. He probado a ponerle un timeout, etc etc, pero es como si no pudiese hacer referencia desde este código a ese objeto (desde la consola del navegador si que puedo). ¿Alguna idea?

Mil gracias.

Edito para incluir parte del código HTML donde está el botón en cuestión.

```
    <div class="pluginContainer" id="com.ibm.bi.authoring.runBtnPluginContainer" style="">
   <div id="com.ibm.bi.authoring.runBtn" class="inlineFlex">
      <button type="button" role="button" title="Run" id="com.ibm.bi.authoring.runBtn.default" class="button undefined menu defaultButton">
         <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM IBM Cognos Products: CoreUI (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2016 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.-->
         <svg class="svgIcon" role="img" aria-label="Run" focusable="false">
            <title>Run</title>
            <use style="pointer-events: none; " xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#authoring-run"></use>
         </svg>
      </button>
      <button type="button" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" title="Run" id="com.ibm.bi.authoring.runBtn.menu" class="button menu comboBox currentlySelected" data-selector="true" aria-describedby="popover288205">
         <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM IBM Cognos Products: CoreUI (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2016 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.-->
         <svg class="svgIcon" role="img" aria-label="‪Run‬" focusable="false">
            <title>‪Run‬</title>
            <use style="pointer-events: none; " xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#common-dropdown"></use>
         </svg>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Si le doy a ver código fuente desde el chrome sale de otro modo, está todo el contenido en un JSON, entiendo que este es el problema:

[Dejo la URL al código en pastebin,porque el código no entra aquí](https://pastebin.com/3cBVchBp)

Comment: Sin ver el HTML es my complicado ayudarte ¿estás seguro de que existe un elemento con ese ID?

Comment: Si, el objeto existe porque desde la consola del navegador si puedo hacer referencia a él, lo que pasa es que la página se carga como por partes (lo siento, no soy experto web). Hasta que no se hace click en este objeto "com.ibm.bi.authoring.runBtn.menu" no existe este "li.commonMenuItem".

Comment: Si ese es el caso, en lugar de "pulsar" un botón, intenta ver qué función se llama al pulsarlo e intenta llamarla directamente